# Prove that $\hat{f}(n)={\frac{2}{\pi(1-4n^2)}}$, given that $f(x)=|sin(\pi x)|$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

Prove that 
$$\hat{f}(n)={\frac{2}{\pi(1-4n^2)}},\ given\ thatf(x)=|sin(\pi x)||,\int_{0}^{1}sin\pi(x)dx={\frac{2}\pi}\\where\ \hat{f}(x)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)e(-nx)dx. \ Use\ the\ fact\ that\\sin\pi(x)={\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{2i}}$$

Here's my attempt 
$$
as\sin(\pi x)={\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{2i}},\ \ f(x)= |{\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{2i}}|=\ {\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{2}}\mathbf{(I\  think\ this \ might\ be\ wrong, perhaps\ I\ should\ find \ the\ norm\ because\ {\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{2}}\ is\ a \ complex\ number } )\\\hat{f}(x)={\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{2}}={\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)e(-nx)dx={\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{2}}e^{-nx}={\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{1} e^{(x(1-2n))/2}- e^{(-x(1+2n))/2}={\frac{1}{2}}(({\frac{2}{1-2n}})(e^{((1-2n)/2)}-1)+({\frac{2}{1
+2n}})(e^{(-(1+2n))/2)}-1))
$$
If I expanded the expression, The nonexponential term comes out to be $\frac{2}{1-4n^{2}}$ but I'm still left with with exponential terms that I can't seem to manipulate $({\frac{2}{1-2n}})(e^{((1-2n)/2)})$ and $({\frac{2}{1
+2n}})(e^{(-(1+2n))/2)})$ into anything simpler.

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with your formula for $sinπ(x)$. Shouldn't it be $sin(πx)$? Then the integral is indeed $2/π$. Secondly $sin(πx)$ is non-negative over the integration interval so the absolute sign is superfluous.

Comment: yes it should be $sin(\pi x)$, and I understand what you're saying about the absolute sign. Still I'll be left with the integral $\int _0^1\:\left(\frac{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}{2i}\right)e^{-nx}dx$ So I'll still run into the same problem with an $2i$ instead of an $2$. Don't I have to simplify the $e^{x}$ functions? Integration by parts seems to make the problem more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

I would get

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin (\pi x) &=&\frac{e^{i\pi x}-e^{-i\pi x}}{2i} \\
\hat{f}(n) &=&\int_{0}^{1}dx\exp [-nx]\frac{e^{i\pi x}-e^{-i\pi x}}{2i} \\
&=&\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{1}dx\{\exp [-(n-i\pi )x]-\exp [-(n+i\pi )x]\}
\end{eqnarray*}
where the integral is trivial